# SSIS Пустой список сопоставления колонок

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio, odbc, ssis

Visual Studio 2022, SSIS 1.1, PsqlODBC 15.00
Добавляю в поток данных источник или назначение ODBC, в Connection manager'е подключение к базе на PostgreSql проходит без ошибок, выбираю необходимую таблицу, на вкладке маппинг список доступных целевых колонок всегда пустой.
Запрос Sql к базе Postgre типа truncate table выполняется без ошибок.
При добавлении источника ODBC с sql запросом внутри во вкладке столбцы список тоже пустой.
Драйвер PGNP OLEDB работает без ошибок, но его стоимость поражает.
Есть ли решение данной проблемы или возможные альтернативы?

Comment: При попытке настроить источник или назначение к базе данных на MsSql через ODBC происходит все то же самое